# Kivy: Trying to get grid layout with buttons to scroll

Tags: android, kivy

Im trying to get familiar with kivy and by doing so I thought I could make a small news feed reader for some of the sites I visit the most. (they all have a rss form)

Im struggling to wrap my head around kivy, it seems to be a new monster in my life.

I have the code below. What I am trying to do is create a list of buttons (which I can do fine) and then have that list scrollable (in some websites there is a lot of news feed).

Im struggling to get the scrollable part in the list. Right now it just tries to put all of the buttons in the bottom of the window which makes it look all squashed and gross, I think this has something to do with the size_hint_y = none, but I know the documentation mentions that you need to disable the hint_y on the gridlayout for the scrollview to work (or at least thats how I interpreted it).

Code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

#Importing modules for data capture for website and reading.
from urllib import urlopen
from re import findall, MULTILINE, sub


#news list data 
heading = []
date = []
id_ref = []

URL_list = 'my_sites.xml'

O_WL = urlopen(URL_list).read()

class Screen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)        
        self.cols = 1
        self.spacing = 2
        self.size_hint_y=None
        for i in range(len(id_ref)):
            btn_new = Button(text = heading[i],height=50, text_size=(300,None),font_size='15sp') 
            self.add_widget(btn_new)
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None,None),size=(400,400))
        root.add_widget(self)

class rss_class(App):
    def build(self):

        O_WL = urlopen(URL_list).read()
        id_ex = findall('<id>(.*)</id>',O_WL)
        for i in id_ex:
            id_ref.extend([i])

        head_ex = findall('<headline>(.*)</headline>',O_WL)
        for i in head_ex:
            heading.extend([i])

        date_ex = findall('<modifiedDate>(.*)</modifiedDate>',O_WL)
        for i in date_ex:
            date.extend([i])
    print id_ref
    return Screen()  

runTouchApp(rss_class())
```

Thanks in advance for the help and guidance.

Comment: Can you please fix indentation for both question and answer.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico, ok updated the code with proper indentations. Wish there was an easier way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of banging head against wall I have managed to answer my own question but this has brought with it many many more unknowns. Oh the joy of learning something new. Haha.

Here is my code that answered my own question. I hope this helps somebody else in the future.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

#Importing modules for data capture for website and reading.
from urllib import urlopen
from re import findall, MULTILINE, sub

#news list data 
heading = []
date = []
id_ref = []

URL_list = 'my_sites.xml'

O_WL = urlopen(URL_list).read()

class Main_app(App):

    O_WL = urlopen(URL_list).read()

    id_ex = findall('<id>(.*)</id>',O_WL)
    for i in id_ex:
        id_ref.extend([i])  

    head_ex = findall('<headline>(.*)</headline>',O_WL)
    for i in head_ex:
        heading.extend([i])
    date_ex = findall('<modifiedDate>(.*)</modifiedDate>',O_WL)
    for i in date_ex:
        date.extend([i]) 

    def build(self):

        Buttonlayout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=2, size_hint_y=None)
        Buttonlayout.bind(minimum_height=Buttonlayout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(len(id_ref)):
            btn = Button(text=heading[i], size_hint_y=None, height=80,text_size=(350,None),font_size='12sp')
            Buttonlayout.add_widget(btn)
        root = ScrollView()
        root.add_widget(Buttonlayout)
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
Main_app().run()
```